# Redux Cannot read Schema Normalizr

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

i always get error like this:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'periodListSchema' of undefined

here is my code:

my Schema

```
import { schema, arrayOf } from 'normalizr';

export const periodSchema = new schema.Entity('activePeriod');
export const periodListSchema = new schema.Array(periodSchema);
```

My Normalize action

```
then(response => {
            console.log('normalized response', normalize(response.schema.periodListSchema));
```

and this is my response

```
{"activePeriod":[{"periodID":2,"periodName":"Periode 27","startDate":"2016-11-11","endDate":"2016-12-11","remark":"Periode Alpha 27","isActive":"1"}],"status":"OK"}
```

My Normalzr library is v3.2.2
can someone help me find out what's wrong?, i'm trying to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'periodListSchema' of undefined` This error has been thrown because `response` does not have `schema` property, therefore you can't get `periodListSchema` property from `undefined`

2) To normalize response, you should pass array of periods to `normalize` func, and specify `schema`. Also, if you have non-standart name of id property, then you should specify the name in options of `schema.Entity` constructor, through `idAttribute`.

[DEMO webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KhHuLhnKITAxdHfiJfC)

**Example**

```js
import { schema, normalize } from 'normalizr';

export const periodSchema = new schema.Entity(
  'activePeriods',
  {},
  { idAttribute:'periodID' }
);
export const periodListSchema = [periodSchema];

const response = {"activePeriod":[{"periodID":2,"periodName":"Periode 27","startDate":"2016-11-11","endDate":"2016-12-11","remark":"Periode Alpha 27","isActive":"1"}],"status":"OK"};

console.log(
  normalize(response.activePeriod, periodListSchema)
);
```

**Result**

```js
{
  "entities": {
    "activePeriods": {
      "2": {
        "periodID": 2,
        "periodName": "Periode 27",
        "startDate": "2016-11-11",
        "endDate": "2016-12-11",
        "remark": "Periode Alpha 27",
        "isActive": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "result": [
    2
  ]
}
```

Comment: i got this error: Error: Unexpected input given to normalize. Expected type to be "object", found "undefined".
    at normalize

Comment: i already fix that. forget to specify more. my  response.data.activePeriod. thx anyway

Comment: @ukiyakimura Can you share by dision please?